# How to set up an email or notification service for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I create an email sending notification service class that I can mock and unit test?

My service is in another layer which is a class library. I'm trying not to import the smtp client, but if this is unavoidable, then its no problem. This is what I have now:

```
public class EmailNotificationService : INotificationService
{
    private readonly EmailNotification _emailNotification;

    public EmailNotificationService(EmailNotification emailNotification)
    {
        _emailNotification = emailNotification;
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        using (var mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            //If no replyto was passed in the notification, then make it null.
            mail.ReplyTo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_emailNotification.ReplyTo) ? null : new MailAddress(_emailNotification.ReplyTo);

            mail.To.Add(_emailNotification.To);
            mail.From = _emailNotification.From;
            mail.Subject = _emailNotification.Subject;
            mail.Body = _emailNotification.Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //this doesn't seem right.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}

public class EmailNotification
{
    public EmailNotification()
    {
        To = "";
        ReplyTo = "";
        Subject = "";
        Body = "";
    }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string ReplyTo { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Sending out email is actually much more complicated than it sounds and than it should be. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: What do you want to test here?  There is very little you can unit test in this class.  Testing that it *actually* sends the email is an integration test.

Comment: what do you expect the EmailNotificationService to do?? Send emails of course... I think you are over-complicating your design

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the unit testing you're facing that this class is throwing up? This class looks fine, I suspect your test is where the real issue lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to import the System.Net.Mail library, you would have to use an interface. Note that this doesn't really help much for your unit testing though

```
public interface IEmailSender{
     void Send(EmailNotification emailNotification);
}
```

and then in your EmailNotificationService class you can add the following property or pass in the IEmailSender in your constructor

```
private IEmailSender emailSender;

public IEmailSender EmailSender
{
     get{
          if(this.emailSender == null){
               //Initialize new EmailSender using either
               // a factory pattern or inject using IOC 
          }
          return this.emailSender
     }
     set{
          this.emailSender = value;
     }
}
```

your Notify method would become

```
public void Notify()
{
    EmailSender.Send(_emailNotification);
}
```

you would then create a concrete class that implements the IEmailSender interface

```
public class MyEmailSender: IEmailSender
{
     public void Send(EmailNotification emailNotification)
     {
        using (var mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            //If no replyto was passed in the notification, then make it null.
            mail.ReplyTo = 
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(_emailNotification.ReplyTo) ? null : 
                    new MailAddress(_emailNotification.ReplyTo);

            mail.To.Add(emailNotification.To);
            mail.From = emailNotification.From;
            mail.Subject = emailNotification.Subject;
            mail.Body = emailNotification.Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(mail);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Rather than having a property backed by a private field for the IEmailSender interface, I'd rather have it passed as a constructor parameter.  But either way, you still don't have anything to test other than your getter returns the appropriate instance, which wasn't in the original code, so the OP still doesn't have anything in his original implementation that can be unit tested.

Comment: there really isn't much to test.. like you said, either it sends the mail or it doesnt